# JTAG connector - large pitch to smaller one

Tags: cables, jtag, debugging, swd

I have a [Segger's Jlink EDU](https://www.segger.com/j-link-edu.html) probe which I used for debugging and programming various ARM based MCU's. But now I have to work with this [LPC4088 QS board](http://www.embeddedartists.com/products/boards/lpc4088_qsb.php) which has a smaller pitch 20-pin JTAG connector that usual one. So I am searching for something like this:

[image]

to transform my large pitch JTAG cable to smaller pitch one. BUT The one on the picture (the smaller one) has only 10 pins while I need 20-pins. Does anyone know of any similar circuit like the one on the picture but with two 20-pin connectors (larger and smaller one)?

This is the schematics of the JTAG interface on my board. It looks like more than 10 pin's are needed:

[image]

Comment: In reality, for an SWD target you need only a ground, SWDIO, SWCLK and *maybe* a reset and an I/O reference voltage (depending on the target and what the design of the tap adapter assumes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [this one](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ulinkpro/ulinkpro_cs_connectors.htm) would work for you:

[image]

Here is [another possibility](https://www.fasttech.com/product/1001900-j-linkjlink-v7-to-v8-20-pin-jtag-adapter) of a somewhat universal JTAG adapter:

[image]

And [finally this is likely](https://www.segger.com/jlink-adapters-19pin-cortexm.html) exactly what you are looking for:

[image]

Comment: @71GA - More likely the 3rd one.

Comment: Thanks! This one is expensive! =) 100€ on Ebay: http://www.ebay.com/itm/ADAPTER-J-LINK-19-PIN-CORTEX-M-Part-8-06-00-/391078652797?hash=item5b0e1aab7d:g:UUcAAOxysE5Sa8Ea and 4x cheaper on official site: http://shop.segger.com/J_Link_19_Pin_Cortex_M_Adapter_p/8.06.00.htm Oh and we really pay for our stupidity. =P

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently. I used some of these breakout cables...

10-pin IDC Socket Rainbow Breakout Cable

Essentiall just bring the JTAG out to individual connectors no matter the pitch.

Answer (score 1):

The standard ARM 20-pin one doesn't have 20 unique pins. For example there are multiple ground pins. That's how they can get away with a 10-pin connector.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I added the schematics for my board's JTAG connector in my question. It looks like it needs more than 10 pins, because it uses MBED interface.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the small cable from the connector on the LPC4088 and cut one of the connectors off. Then slit the wires of the flat cable apart to solder onto connector pin tails of a connector like this:

[image]

After the wires are all attached you could pot the connections in hot melt glue or epoxy.

[I have made similar type adapters](http://www.carousel-design.com/5mmFLEX.html) in the past albeit for a different type of application. Here is a picture of one such.

[image]

Comment: Hahahaha. I was thinking of doing something like this myself but never thought of epoxy. =) Still I'd perfer to design a PCB to make the transition from the small pitch to large pitch. But ideal would be to just not waste my time and buy one.

Comment: Well the urgency of need often drives the solution. Adapters if available can also be expensive because they tend to be low volume devices. Clearly if time, both expended effort and time duration are not critical factors then making a PC board and building an adapter is a better solution if you cannot find a commercial solution.